# Store File To External Storage Not Working For Android 10 and above - Android Studio/Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-10.0, android-external-storage

My app has an extract button that takes the data from text view and paste it in a text file "Ledger.txt". It creates a folder in Mobile internal Storage Root Directory "WaterLedger" and place a Ledger.txt file in it and if the text file is already present it appends the text in the file. **The code is only working till android 9 not above.**

In Android 10 on pressing Extract button it asks "grant permission to write file in storage" but even if you press Yes it still wont create folder (WaterLerger) and paste/update data in Text File (Ledger.txt)

Here is the code

```
class WriteFile: AsyncTask<String, Int, String>() {
private val mFolder = "/WaterLedger"
lateinit var folder: File
internal var writeThis = "string to cacheApp.txt"
internal var cacheApptxt = "Ledger.txt"
override fun doInBackground(vararg writethis: String): String? {
    val received = writethis[0]
    if(received.isNotEmpty()){
        writeThis = received
    }
    folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"$mFolder/")
    if(!folder.exists() || folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir()
        val readME = File(folder, cacheApptxt)
        val file = File(readME.path)
        val out: BufferedWriter
        try {
            out = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(file, true), 1024)
            out.write("****Ledger Updated On Dated:$currentDate*****\n")
            out.newLine()
            out.write(writeThis)
            out.newLine()
            out.close()
            Log.d("Output_Success", folder.path)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Output_Exception", "$e")
        }
    }
    return folder.path

}
```

// Driver Code

```
extract.setOnClickListener {

        var pathToFileCreated = ""
        val anRW = ReadandWrite().readAndwriteStorage(this, this)
        if (anRW) {
            pathToFileCreated = WriteFile().execute("$StringBuilder").get()
            Log.d("pathToFileCreated", pathToFileCreated)


            Toast.makeText(this,"File Saved",android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: You do not have rights on Android 11+ to create arbitrary directories off of the external storage root, unless your `targetSdkVersion` is 29 or lower. And that will no longer be an option in a few months. You will need to do something else, such as use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you External Pictures directory URI (You can create your desirable directory into it):

```
private fun createTextURI(): Uri? {
    val imageCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    else
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

    val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "$fileName.txt")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
    }

    val finalURI = contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)
    resultUri = finalURI
    return finalURI
}
```

Use this URI for file creation like this:

```
new File(finalURI.getPath());
```

And write into this file which you created above. ✌

Make sure you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Ref. [Demo App](https://github.com/absolute-vijju/ActivityContract)